# Balanced vs Unbalanced Binary Tree - Clarification Needed

Tags: java, binary-tree

I am in need of some clarification, this may be a really stupid question and I have done research but cannot find a clear answer to my question. My question is, **What are some property differences between a balanced binary tree and an unbalanced binary tree?** I was asked this on an interview (java questions) and I had explained to the interviewer the differences however he mentioned that he wants to know the properties that differentiate between the two (binary tree - unbalanced vs balanced).

If someone can please clarify this for me, i'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What specifically would you like clarification on? Have you found some resources explaining balanced binary trees which you didn't understand?

Comment: What does it mean exactly by "properties"?

Comment: That's a bit vague, it could be implementation details, the time complexity of the operations, the formal conditions defining whether a tree is "balanced" or not... I suggest investigating all of them, and if that kind of question comes up in an interview again, ask for clarification from the interviewer.

Comment: I see, well thank you so much for explaining this. I will definitely look into these to prepare in case it does pop up again. Will do, thank again!

Comment: There is only one 'property' that may be different, and that is the difference between the heights under each node, which is constrained in the case of a balanced tree and unconstrained otherwise, and that in turn leads to a performance upper bound in the case of a balanced tree. It's a poorly phrased question, if that's what the interviewer really said.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! But yes, I believed so as well.

Answer (score 15):

By "properties", I believe the interviewer was asking about Big-O performance complexity.

With a balanced tree, access<sup>1</sup> is *O(log n)*.
With an unbalanced tree, access<sup>1</sup> is *O(n)* (worst case).

That is because an unbalanced tree built from sorted data is effectively the same as a linked list.

[image]

The space complexity is the same for both types of trees.

<sup>*1) Access covers lookup, insert, and remove operations.*</sup>

Comment: Simple and direct thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think Andreas's answer is on point, but you need to know the inner workings of a binary tree and linked list to appreciate it. Seems this is what the interviewer is quizzing you on: do you know what he's talking about when he brings up the structure, and can you comfortably walk through it to derive a reasonable answer?

Another way to think about the question is to shift the focus on the **balanced** tree. What makes it balanced? For each level, the height of the left subtree is the same as the right one, so every root at that level has either two nodes or one node. An unbalanced one is the opposite.

Now that you understand what an unbalanced vs balanced tree looks like, you can start comparing their implementations. What is the implementation for binary search? You keep halving the tree until the target is located. As a pattern, every time you deal with a problem that involves halving the amount of inputs, that's log(N), since we're working with base of x,

```
log(aN) = x => a^x = N
```

So the worst case runtime of a balanced search tree is O(log(N)), where the target is either not found or at the very last position, you're halving N inputs (log(N)).

For the *unbalanced* search tree, the worst case scenario is the same where the target is not found or at the very last position, but because the tree is unbalanced, instead of halving, you're going through every item in a linear way. Therefore, the runtime is O(N).

What does the runtime of the unbalanced tree mean in relation to the balanced tree? If you consider the runtime order, O(N) is slower than O(logN), which is why a balanced tree is usually the better structure.